# [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recordTypeInfos')]]

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, js

I am trying to display my LWC for a specific recordType. The component works fine otherwise but **after my session ends and when I log in again** or sometimes even when **I edit my record page to reposition my LWC** I am shown this error:

```
[LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recordTypeInfos')]]
```

I was facing this issue in full sandbox first but now I am also facing this issue in dev sandbox and since it doesn't happen everytime I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I am using two wire methods.
One to fetch the object details. Another to fetch the record details inside which I am matching the recordTypeId of the record with my specific recordTypeId.

Below is my JS code:

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import {getRecord, getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import CUSTOMOP_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.CustomOPField__c';
const FIELDS = [CUSTOMOP_FIELD];

export default class DisplayLWC extends LightningElement {

@track displayData = [];
@api recordId;
@track customOPRecordTypeId;
@track isCustomOPRecord = false;
@api objectApiName;

//@wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName : OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT})objectInfo;


@track objectInfo;
@wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName : OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT})
    wiredObject(result){
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectInfo = result.data;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }

@wire(getRecord, {recordId:'$recordId',fields:FIELDS})
    wiredRecord({error,data}) {
        if(error){
            let message = 'Unknown error';
            if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
            } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
                message = error.body.message;
            }
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error while loading',
                    message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        } else if(data){
            if(this.objectInfo.data && this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos){
                const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
                const rtInfo= Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'CustomOPRecordType');
                this.customOPRecordTypeId = rtInfo;
                if(data.recordTypeId == this.customOPRecordTypeId && data.fields.CustomOPField__c.value){
                    this.isCustomOPRecord = true;
                    //Then i am executing my logic here//
                    try{
                       //executing some more logic here//
                       let tempData = [];
                       //defining my tempData here//
                       this.displayData = tempData;
                    }catch{
                    console.error('Error',error);
                    }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my html:

```html
<template>
   <template if:true={objectInfo.data>
    <template if:true={isCustomOPRecord>
        <lightning-card title="Custom LWC">
           <template for:each={displayData} for:item="disDat" for:index="index">
               <!--Some more html code -->
           </template>            
        <lightning-card>
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after considering the inputs from @sdandamud1, I made a couple of changes in my code i.e, by holding the provisioned value for later and by fetching the specific recordTypeId in my first wire method itself and then using it to match with my record's recordTypeId inside my getRecord wire method.
The final working version of my code looks like this:

JS:

```js
@track customOPRecordTypeId;
@track isCustomOPRecord = false;
@api objectApiName;
@track objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    wiredObject(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectInfo = result.data;
            const rtis = this.objectInfo.recordTypeInfos;
            this.customOPRecordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'CustomOPRecordType');
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId:'$recordId',fields:FIELDS})
    wiredRecord({error,data}) {
         if(error){
                //handle your error
         }if(data){
             if(data.recordTypeId == this.customOPRecordTypeId && data.fields.CustomOPField__c.value){
                    this.isCustomOPRecord = true;
                    //Executing my logic here
             }
         }
    }
```

and in my html i am surrounding my code with `<template if:true={objectInfo}>`

If anybody finds this useful then kindly upvote it so that it may help others too.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend hold the provisioned value for later otherwise you will lost when ever  [Object Destructur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the wired result. added sample code

```
@track objectinfo; 
    @wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName : OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT})
wiredobjectinfo({data,error}){
if(data){this.objectinfo = data; }
else if(error){console.error(error);}



@wire(getRecord, {recordId:'$recordId',fields:FIELDS})
wiredRecord({error,data}) {
    if(data){
        if(this.objectinfo  && this.objectinfo.recordTypeInfos){
            const rtis = this.objectinfo.recordTypeInfos;
            const rtInfo= Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'CustomOPRecordType');
            this.customOPRecordTypeId = rtInfo;
}
```

Comment: Hi sdandamud1, This makes sense. Will need to check once my session ends, But what about the html. Do i still need to surround my entire html code with ```<template if:true={dummyResult.data} ``` tag ?

Comment: yes, if any of your html template elements rendering depends on `dummyResult.data`

Comment: Hi sdandamud1, I've updated my code as you had suggested but now I am getting a new error : ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')``` .

Comment: updated , can you check now

Comment: Hi sdandamud1, I checked with the updated code. Now, the lwc is now not visible in the record page. Not sure why this is happening!

Comment: use `objectinfo` instead  `objectinfo.data` in your HTML.

Comment: Hi sdandamud1,  the lwc is getting displayed now, did not face any such issue related to recordTypeInfos till now so i guess this works. Thanks!

Comment: can you upvote to answer if works, so it'll help to others

Comment: I tried but there is a popup saying i can't yet but my feedback has been recorded.